# Fetch multiple fields in relation_aggregate expression

Tags: qgis, aggregation, relation

In the QGIS 3.34+ expression builder, how could one use the expression parameter in the [`relation_aggregate`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#relation-aggregate) to fetch multiple fields?

E.g.:

```
relation_aggregate( 
    relation:= 'my_relation', 
    aggregate:= 'array_agg', 
    expression:= "rep_lyr,rep_id",
    concatenator:= "; "
)
```

but this doesn't work.

The goal is to fetch related data in a many to many join table as follow:

| id | ref_id | rep_lyr | rep_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | lyrB | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | lyrC | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | lyrB | 7 |
| 4 | 5 | lyrA | 8 |
| 5 | 9 | lyrB | 11 |
| 6 | 7 | lyrB | 11 |

I'm trying to set up labels for my features:

[image]

Comment: "rep_lyr,rep_id"is not a valid expression nor a valid field name, could you give an exemple of what you want as result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to concatenate the field values like so:

```sql
relation_aggregate( 
    relation:= 'my_relation', 
    aggregate:= 'array_agg', 
    -- field values concatenated into a string separated by a comma
    expression:= "rep_lyr" || ',' || "rep_id"
)
```